# Is this sentence well formed?

Tags: orthography, semantics, translation, french

I want a well formed sentence in english GB and US (two sentences if necessary…) from this french sentence:

> Cette page n'existe pas dans cette langue. Voici son contenu original :

Here is what Google Translate give to me:

> This page does not exist in that language. Here is his original content:

Is this sentence well formed, compared to the requirements that I have outlined?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change *his* to *its*. It's difficult to comment beyond that without knowing the full context.